# Dropbox cannot work on my Ubuntu 13.10 laptop

Tags: dropbox, ubuntu-13.10

Dropbox is not working on my laptop ubuntu 13.10, it is keep saying connecting and the Dropbox icon on the menu bar is grey.

I tried to install Dropbox with the following ways and all failed.
1) sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox

2) install from Ubuntu Software Center

3) downloads dropbox .deb file from dropbox offical website

Finally, I re-install my laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and tried with 1) I mentioned above, and it works.

Is there anyone know why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Add Dropbox’s repository key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
```

Add Dropbox’s repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu saucy main"
```

update and install Dropbox

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

1. When prompted with the screen, click Next.
2. Click Start Dropbox to continue.

---

You can see that Saucy is available at http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/ so it should be working.

Comment: I tried this and it was not working for me. I got those installation commands from Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This should work for 13.10, saucy is available here http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/

Answer (score 0):

**These two lines will fix your problem:**

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist

dropbox start -i
```